# colocar elementos de uma tabela numa lista

Tags: javascript, array, table

Eu tenho uma tabela vazia , e depois um codigo javascript que permite preencher a tabela através de input. O que pretendo é colocar toda a informação dessa tabela num array(inpendentemente do numero de linhas e colunas da tabela) de modo a que depois consiga mais tarde eliminar elementos no array e alterem automaticamente na tabela.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nomedisciplina">    
<button onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar disciplina</button><br>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function adicionar() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("nomedisciplina").value;
}
```

[image: O que pretendo é que apareça na tabela a ordem que aparece na lista]

Comment: Você já considerou utilizar angular ou jquery? vai facilitar demais o que você quer fazer

Comment: Como é que faria em Jquery ?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a parte _"preencher a tabela através de input"_? como seria isso na prática? colocar a array no input e a tabela ser alterada? on de está essa array? no código ou em texto/json?

Comment: Eu tenho uma tabela vazia e através do input com o id="nomedisciplinas" mete esse valor na tabela( tabela de uma coluna ) , esse e  o codigo que ja tenho , agora a minha duvida e como meto a informaçao ja presente na tabela num array de modo associar para caso mais tarde eu precisar de eliminar num lado eliminar noutro

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer com essa array e como mudando a array esperas que a tabela seja alterada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

TABLE:

```
<table id="dataTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Descricao</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>José</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Maria</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var table = document.getElementById( "dataTable" );
var tableArr = [];
for ( var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
    tableArr.push({
        codigo: table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML,
        descricao: table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML
    });
}
console.log(tableArr);
```

Veja o jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xL6hbxga/

Comment: Está-me a dar um problema, com o codigo que pus na questão para adicionar elementos a tabela , vai dar uma coluna da tabela por exemplo , ao adicionar o elemento " a "  , a tabela fica só com o "a" , depois se adicionar "b" , a tabela fica "b,a" enquanto que o array vai ficar [a,b] como tem de ser , sabe o que posso mudar no meu código para acrescentar elementos a tabela de modo a dar correto ?

Comment: Não compreendi bem como é a tabela, podes postar na pergunta como é a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: ja coloquei uma foto